# Tell Us The Day!

Tags: logical-deduction

A group of campers have been on vacation so long, that they've forgotten the day of the week. The following conversation ensues.
'

> Darryl: What's the day? I don't think it is Thursday, Friday or Saturday.
>
> Tracy: Well that doesn't narrow it down much. Yesterday was Sunday.
>
> Melissa: Yesterday wasn't Sunday, tomorrow is Sunday.
>
> Ben: The day after tomorrow is Saturday.
>
> Adrienne: The day before yesterday was Thursday.
>
> Susie: Tomorrow is Saturday.
>
> David: I know that the day after tomorrow is not Friday.

**If only one person's statement is true, what day of the week is it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The day is...

> Wednesday

All you have to do is...

> Check off what days of the week each person thinks it could be, and the correct day is the one with only one check mark (given by Darryl, the only correct person):
>
>  `Day      | S | M | T | W | Th | F | Sa |`
>  `Darryl   | x | x | x | x |    |   |    |`
>  `Tracy    |   | x |   |   |    |   |    |`
>  `Melissa  |   |   |   |   |    |   | x  |`
>  `Ben      |   |   |   |   | x  |   |    |`
>  `Adrienne |   |   |   |   |    |   | x  |`
>  `Susie    |   |   |   |   |    | x |    |`
>  `David    | x | x | x |   | x  | x | x  |`

Answer (score 3):

The day is

> Wednesday, and Darryl's statement is accurate.

This can be determined as follows:

> Darryl and David make statements about what day it is not, while the other campers make statements identifying a certain day.  It cannot be Monday, Tuesday, or Sunday, because then both Darryl and David would be correct.  The day also cannot be Thursday, as both Ben and David would be correct. Friday would make both Susie and David correct, and Saturday would make Melissa and David correct.  Thus, only Wednesday leaves one camper correct.

Comment: Correct! Good jobbb